# an example related to derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

How can I construct an example of the following?

$f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ but $\lim_{x\to x_0} f'(x)$ does not exist?

A bit stupid but if a function that doesn't have a limit at a point does that mean left hand limit is not equal to the right hand limit?

Can I construct $f$ such that $f=0$ for all $x\in (-\infty,0]$ and $f=\sin(x)$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$ and take $x_0$ to be at zero?

Comment: A function may have neither left hand limit nor right hand limit, or one of the two. However, if the left hand limit is not equal to the right hand limit, the limit cannot exist.

Comment: Your given example is not differentiable at $0$. Note that the right derivative is $1$, and the left derivative is $0$.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof is it because the left hand derivative is 0 but the right hand derivative is 1 and hence not differentiable?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof also could you please construct a function that doesn't have left hand limit at a point so that I can understand bit better?

Comment: Yes. For the derivative to exist, right and left hand derivatives must be equal. As to your second comment, I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I meant as in general, is there an example such that a function is defined on [a,b], say, (I know that the left hand limit doesn't exist when x=a) but will at any other points in [a,b] such that the left hand limit does not exist? (This side question is not related to my main question) Thanks!

Comment: Are you inquiring about a function which is defined on $[a,b]$, whose left limit is not defined on the entire interval? The function which assigns $0$ to rational numbers and $1$ to irrational ones would be an example of that.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Ah yes so would that mean that your function has no right limit for all $[a,b]$ and hence the function has no limit for all $x$ in $[a,b]$?

Comment: My function has neither left nor right limit on the interval, and therefore has no limit, yes. There exist functions which have a right limit but no left limit in a point; I'm not sure if there are functions which have a right limit but no left limit on an *interval*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f$ is differentiable everywhere, but the limit $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ doesn't exist, since, if $x\neq0$,$$f'(x)=2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)-\cos\left(\frac1x\right)$$and, although the limite $\lim_{x\to0}2x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ exists (it is equal to $0$), the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\cos\left(\frac1x\right)$ doesn't.

Comment: That is a great example! On a unrelated note, how can I prove that $f'(x)$ of your function is discontinuous at $0$?

Comment: I have expanded my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: hmm I understand that part but are we saying if a point in a function has no limit then it's not continuous at that point? and why?

Comment: If the limit of a function $f$ at a point $a$ doesn't exist, then $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, since asserting that $f$ is continuous at $a$ means that the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists and it is equal to $f(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

This link describes a pathological function which is only differentiable at $0$.

https://collegemathteaching.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/a-real-valued-function-that-is-differentiable-at-an-isolated-point/